# command with args doesn't work in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to do is to make the command work like this: `/changeicon (server id here)`

My code:

```js
client.on("message", message => { 
    if(!message.author.id === config.ownerID) return;
    if(message.content === '/changeicon'){
        var guild = client.guilds.cache.get(args[0]);
        guild.setIcon('./icon.jpg')
}})
```

This doesn't work, it just simply doesn't run the command, nothing happens, no crash and no error log.

Comment: You shouldn't turn `message.author.id` to a boolean with `!`. Use `if(message.author.id !== config.ownerID)`. Also, if the message is not exactly `/changeicon`, your bot will do nothing. Try to read the basics on https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#listening-for-messages

Comment: Doesn't seem like you've implemented an `args` array. Also as @Zslot Meszaros says, you check for `/changeicon`. That if statement will never fire with additional input

Comment: _"redirecting me to other sites isn't really helping me"_ Why do you think so? Your code is full of errors and the link I provided would solve your issues. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You'll find your experience here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

There is so many things wrong with this:

1. You just turned `message.author.id` into a boolean, so this is as if you were checking if `config.ownerID` was equal to `false`
2. You are checking if the message content is exactly equal to "/changeicon", if the message content is `/changeicon 123456765624` it wouldn't work
3. You didn't show how/when you made your `args` variable so it's really hard to help you.
   If it's a string then you are getting the first character of the string.
4. You are using `client.guilds.cache.get(` which will only work if the guild is cached (if there were any messages recieved in that guild since the last restart of your bot)
   Use `client.guilds.fetch("id")`
5. You didn't await the function you used to fetch the guild. Because of this it returns a promise not a guild object.

   ```
   client.on("message", message => {
       if(message.author.id !== config.ownerID) return;
       if(message.content.startsWith('/changeicon ')){
           var guild = await client.guilds.fetch(args[0]);
           guild.setIcon('./icon.jpg')
       }
   })
   ```